# Receiving message from channel as guard

Tags: spin, promela

```
A: if
   :: q?a -> ...
   :: else -> ...
   fi
```

> Note that a race condition is built-in to this type of code. How long
>   should the process wait, for instance, before deciding that the
>   message receive operation will not be executable? The problem can be
>   avoided by using message poll operations, for instance, as follows:

The above citation comes from http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/else.html

I cannot understand that argumentation. Just Spin can decide on `q?a`:
if `q` is empty then it is executable. Otherwise, it is blocking.

The given argument raised a race condition.

But, I can make the same argument:

```
byte x = 1;
A: if 
   :: x == 2 -> ...
   :: else -> ...
   fi
```

It is ok from point of Spin's view. But, I am asking, How long should the process wait, for instance, before deciding that the value of `x` will not be incremented by other process?

Answer (score 1):

The argumentation is sound with respect to the semantics of Promela and the selection construct. Note that for selection, if multiple guard statements are executable, one of them will be selected non-deterministically. This in turns implies the semantics such that selection (even though it can non-deterministally execute guards) needs to determine which guards *are executable* at the point of invocation of the selection statement.

The question about the race condition might make more sense when considering the semantics of selection and message receives. Note that race condition in this case means that the output of the selection might *depend on the time for which it needs to invoke the receive* (i.e. whether it finishes at a point at which there is a message in the channel or not).
More specifically, for the selection statement, there should be no ambiguity in terms of feasible guards. Now, the message receive gets the message from the channel only if the channel is not empty (otherwise, it cannot finish executing and waits). Therefore, with respect to the semantics of receive, it is not clear whether it is executable before it is actually executed. In turn, `else` should execute if the receive is not executable. However, since `else` should execute only if `?` is not executable, so to know if `else` is executable the program needs to know the future (or determine how much should it wait to know this, thus incurring the race condition).

Note that the argument does not apply to your second example:

```
byte x = 1;
A: if 
   :: x == 2 -> ...
   :: else -> ...
   fi
```

since here, to answer whether `else` is eligible no waiting is required (nor knowing the future), since the program can at any point determine if `x == 2`.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I don't think I understood most of what you said, except that my answer is not clear (for which, I can agree).
There are two main points in my answer: 1) we need to be able to answer which guards are eligible to be able to answer if `else` should be executed, 2) eligibility of `?` is not clear, since it can potentially block indefinitely. Now, hypothetically, if we allow `?` in a guard, then we need to answer how do we determine if `?` is eligible: do we wait for a message? If yes, for how long? Note that this is not the case with `x==2`, which can be answered without waiting.

Comment: Ok, you told us you know Spin; can you now please tell us which part of the argument of the answer you don't understand?

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to arrive at a conclusion if you proposed how *you think* `?` should behave with `else` and then we can go from there?

Comment: @J.Doe I do not quite understand for what are you thankful for in this case. Can you please tell us if you think this answers your question and if not, then why not? (So we can try to work towards a better answer, if possible.)

Comment: @ivcha, I agree with Patrick. You don't answer my question. You just rewrite my doubt. Two last Patrick's comments explain why your answer is a different way to express what I am asking in fact.

Comment: @J.Doe I agree my answer might be unclear or perhaps dowright incorrect. However, you are accusing me of rewriting/rehashing your question. That is disrespectful and made me regret the time I spent trying to answer your question (and helping you).

Comment: Note that message receive is not necesarilly blocking, but it might be. You are right in that this indeed is a design choice. However, my argument is that this design choice *is consistent* with the semantics of receive. Moreover, it is not about ambigouity (e.g. you might imagine if that simply ignores `?`), it's about the design choise that makes the most sense. More specifically, per your suggestions: 1) returning `true` always would make `else` have no effect, 2) "return `false` when no message is available" is exactly what polling does (and is allowed to be used with `else`).

Comment: Also, note that there is no amgibuouity in the code nor in the verification process. There is no sensible way of "letting the developer to deal with waits"; as I tried to argue, the question is *when is `else`* branch enabled (and a design choice that makes sense having that in mind).

Comment: (I've rewritten and reordered my last two comments since formatting did not come out correctly before.)

Comment: I am in the process of reviewing all Q/A of last year about spin/promela, so I read again your answer and comments. After some thought, I think you correctly nailed it with your explanation, although perhaps the answer could be improved to be more clear. Also, I would like to apologize for the mess that resulted from my own confusion when I first read this answer. +1